# flex data grid visibility when empty

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, header, visibility

I have data grid that measures the height according to the rows it has, but i need to disappear/ make invisible when i have no data, so the header will not just appear alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dataProvider each time it's updated. If after update it's empty, then set your `DataGrid` `visible` (and in case of need `includeInLayout`) property to `false`. Set it back to `true` when on update dataProvider has soma data again.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to check it in the dataGrid: `visible={myDataProvider!=null &amp;&amp; myDataProvider.length>0}`